# Implementing Spark DataSource with WriteSupport

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I'm trying to make my custom Spark DataSource to write my Datasets into files where I have a first line of metadata (a timestamp of file creation for example), then my rows and a footer line with the numbers of data rows.

This is a format imposed by an external service I wish to send the files to, so I have no opportunity to change this rule.

Following Spark documentation I implemented a DataSourceV2 as follow :

```
public class FooDataSource implements DataSourceV2, WriteSupport, DataSourceRegister {
    
    public FooDataSource () {}

    @Override
    public Optional<DataSourceWriter> createWriter(String writeUUID, StructType schema, SaveMode mode, DataSourceOptions options) {
        return Optional.of(new FooDataSourceWriter());
    }

    @Override
    public String shortName() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

So the actual data handling will be done in DataSourceWriter implementation.

```
public class FooDataSourceWriter implements DataSourceWriter {

    @Override
    public DataWriterFactory<InternalRow> createWriterFactory() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void commit(WriterCommitMessage[] messages) {

    }

    @Override
    public void abort(WriterCommitMessage[] messages) {

    }
}
```

And I start to get lost here. I have found no example of an implementation of this DataSourceWriter interface.

Reading the spark documentation I understood that a `DataSource` creates a `DataSourceWriter` for itself, which in turn creates a `DataWriterFactory` which is serialized to each executor nodes alongside a partition of my `Dataset` where the factory will create a `DataWriter` that will do the writing for a partition with a signature `void write(T record)` of the DataWriter interface.

I have a number of question:

1. What do I do with my `void write(T record)` ? Documentation says this method "writes one record". Where do I create `File` or an `BufferedOutputStream` or anything ? Am I supposed to create the file in constructor and append a record in the write method ?
2. Where do I have the opportunity to add my custom header and footer lines ? Again, when creating line in constructor for header and when calling commit for footer ?
3. What is the commit method supposed to do ? Documentation says it is to be called when writing is finished. How do I detect that writing is finished ? Return type is an empty interface `WriterCommitMessage`. What am I supposed to do with this ?

I am lost in the documentation and an explanation of where to insert the missing elements, or working example of implementation of datasource with writing support, would really really help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the implementations to guide you [SingleDirectoryDataWriter](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormatDataWriter.scala#L138) creates the file/path in the constructor. (point 1 and the header from point 2)

It's write function does checking if a new file should be written out or not, then writes to the file. (possibly point 2 relevant)

Abort and commit are as you'd expect them to be and, for commit, is the place to finish your footer (definitely point 2 and 3 relevant).  Close is interesting as that above example does nothing in it's close, I'd expect at least another check at releaseResources there.

You don't decide when data is finished being written, Spark does and calls commit when it's finished.

Look at other pieces of the code to see how partitions/concurrent writes are handled, the docs can only get you so far.

wrt. WriterCommitMessage, it's docs are clear - you, as the implementer of a data source, can use what you wish there (your class must be serializable).  You could, for example, use it to pass the number of rows written for each partition to write a total row etc.